# Feel more involved in/with

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Do I need to use 'in' or 'with' in the following sentence?

'Some images, like the ones of the wounded civilian, have been shot up close, making you feel more involved in/with what they show.'

Thanks

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/202096/involved-in-or-involved-with

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267751/is-it-involved-with-or-involved-in/267787

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/91281/be-involved-in-with